# ReactJS Radiobutton-Group with multiple varibales

Tags: javascript, reactjs, radio-button

I'm trying to build a Radiobutton-Group in ReactJS just like this:
[image]

I'm also using the Bootstrap custom radiobutton.

First of all I made this component:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import FormsStatic from "../FormsStatic";

class IPMRadiobutton extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    render() {
        const uniqueId = FormsStatic.guid();
        return (
            <div className="custom-control custom-radio">
                <input
                    type="radio"
                    className="custom-control-input"
                    id={"others-" + uniqueId}
                    checked={this.props.checked}
                    onChange={this.props.onChange}
                    disabled={this.props.readOnly}
                />
                <label className="custom-control-label" style={{ 'fontWeight': 'normal' }} htmlFor={"others-" + uniqueId}>
                    <p>{this.props.description ? this.props.description : ""}</p>
                </label>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

IPMRadiobutton.propTypes = {
    className: PropTypes.string,
    onChange: PropTypes.func,
    readOnly: PropTypes.bool,
    description: PropTypes.string,
    checked: PropTypes.bool
}

export default IPMRadiobutton;
```

Now I want to use this Radiobuttons like this:

```
   <IPMRadiobutton {...this.props.formControlProps} checked={variable1} description="H-Akte" name="Akte" onChange={() => { console.log("Do i have to change the variable1 and variable2 here?") }} />
   <IPMRadiobutton {...this.props.formControlProps} checked={variable2} description="U-Akte" name="Akte" onChange={() => { console.log("Do i have to change the variable1 and variable2 here?") }} />
```

My problem is that every radiobutton should be bind to one variable (or rather change all variables of the other radiobuttons in the "onChange-event"). So if I check the first Radiobutton, variable1 should be set to true and variable2 should be set to false.

How can i accomplish this task with my component?

Or is there any better way to do this (like a complete other concept)?

Answer (score 0):

If you are need this to work in a production on some pretty important project i would recommend you to use some react plugin for this.You can find it out there,trust me.But if you are tinkering with react an enjoying your time coding you can check my (ugly but with some idea) example.

You can create your own RadioGroup component using this idea.Passing `options` to the RadioGroup and letting the component render radio inputs based on the property seems like an easy way to solve it.But this solution is no perfect but i find it easy to apply.

I think that passing value to the RadioGroup component and update the value by passing onChange callback to the component is good because you will want to save this value anyway also not storing internal value inside RadioGroup component is making it more reactive which in turn simplify value synchronizing with external source.

As a bonus i have added `multiSelect` prop to the RadioGroup, just for fun!
What do you think, Daniel?

```js
class RadioOption extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this)
    }
    render() {
        const { onChange, option: { description, ...restOptionProps }, ...restProps } = this.props
        return (
            <div className="custom-control custom-radio">
                <input
                    type="radio"
                    className="custom-control-input"
                    onChange={this.onChange}
                    {...restProps}
                    {...restOptionProps}
                />
                <label className="custom-control-label" style={{ 'fontWeight': 'normal' }} htmlFor={this.props.option.id}>
                    <p>{description ? description : ""}</p>
                </label>
            </div>
        )

    }

    onChange() {
        this.props.onToggle(this.props.option)
    }

}


class IPMRadioGroup extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)


        this.onRadioOptionToggle = this.onRadioOptionToggle.bind(this)
        this.isChecked = this.isChecked.bind(this)
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="radio-group-container">
                {this.props.options.map(option => {
                    return (
                        <RadioOption checked={this.isChecked(option)} key={option.id} onToggle={this.onRadioOptionToggle} option={option} />
                    )
                })}
            </div>
        )
    }

    isChecked(option) {

        return this.props.value.some(currentOption => option.id === currentOption.id)

    }

    onRadioOptionToggle(option) {

        let value = [].concat(this.props.value)
        let valueFound = false;
        let updatedValue = value.reduce((values, currentValue) => {

            if (currentValue.id === option.id) {
                valueFound = true;
                return values
            }

            if (!this.props.multiSelect) {
                return values
            }

            return values.concat(currentValue)
        }, [])

        if (!valueFound) { updatedValue.push(option) }
        this.props.onChange(updatedValue)

    }

}

IPMRadioGroup.defaultProps = {
    value: [],
    multiSelect: false,
}




class Example extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            radioGroupValue: []
        }
        this.onRadioGroupChange = this.onRadioGroupChange.bind(this)
    }

    render() {
        return (
        <div>
            <IPMRadioGroup onChange={this.onRadioGroupChange} value={this.state.radioGroupValue} options={[
                { description: 'test1', id: "uniqueId1", disabled: true },
                { description: 'test2', id: "uniqueId2" },
                { description: 'test3', id: "uniqueId3" },
            ]} />
            Current Selection {JSON.stringify(this.state.radioGroupValue)}
            </div>
        )
    }

    onRadioGroupChange(value) {
        this.setState({radioGroupValue:value})
    }

}

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById('example'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.js"></script>

<div id="example"></div>
```

As a side note i have used some cool feauters like:

- [Spread operator](https://zhenyong.github.io/react/docs/jsx-spread.html)
- [Destructuring ES6](http://2ality.com/2015/01/es6-destructuring.html)

I like the usage of prop-types! Cheers!